# Communication failure during handshake. Is there a server running on localhost:3306?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, database-connection

I've just upgraded my server to Suse 11.4 & I'm using MySQL 5 & Java 6 and systinet as my web server.
When I try to log in my application I can't seem to view my database and when I check the log on systinet it gives me an error:

> Impossible to create a JDBC connection
>   |  Communication failure during handshake.
>   Is there a server running on localhost:3306?".

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. App should have mysql connector jar file. Originally I had some old versioned jar file, I replaced it with 5.1 compatible connector jar version.

One more simple way to confirm that you have driver in your java environment is do #import for that Driver class.

e.g. If `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")`; is your Driver class then temorarily type `#import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;`
See if there is any build error, fix it, query should work.

Answer (score 0):

Answer a question, that is given, is there a database server running on localhost - 3306 port? See `netstat`, if mysql service is listening to localhost:3306 and additionally, if the user, you are using, has access to localhost, on database, you want to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Update your mysql-connector-java version.

I had the same issue, when I updated 
     mysql-connector-java:2.0.14 to mysql-connector-java:5.1.22 
it worked perfectly